# EKF-SLAM: What would be the consequences of ignoring correlations between landmarks?

Tags: slam

While implementing EKF SLAM, I noticed that the covariance matrix quickly begins to gain correlations between landmarks. These correlations get very expensive as the landmark count increases. I wondered what would be the consequence of simply ignoring these correlations all together.

I would only keep the correlations between the robot pose and each of the landmarks.

In my case, the depth of the landmarks start out with very high uncertainty, and I measure only the bearing to the landmarks. If I never computed the correlations between the landmarks, would the depths of the landmarks converge?

Intuitively, I would think that a measurement of a landmarks bearing vector would only impact that landmark's bearing vector and depth, and the pose.

Thanks